# Manually trigger cell select TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5

I need to manually programmatically trigger a cell select on my tableView. Essentially running the pre-made function

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I'm doing this in order to when an item is deleted from the tableView it will automatically load the next item. However when I try to manually call this function it can't seem to be found. I've tried

```
self.tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath
```

and

```
[tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath]
```

but neither is recognised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];
```

replace selectedIndexPath with whatever the next row is

make sure self is your table view delegate

edit: I know this is an old question but really this should be done with 
`[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];`

Comment: how do I select the next indexPath so for example if row 1 is selected I want to select row 0

Comment: you can create an index path with [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:whateverRow inSection:whateverSection]; use whatever logic you like for the row and section

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
[self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:YourIndexPath]
```